# Node.js/ejs not functioning

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am new to Node.js. I try to learn Node.js and make a simple blog based on the Node.js that I learn. I face a problem in my coding as my node.js syntax is not functioning. I have a coding error in index.ejs, and I can't seem to connect to MongoDB until I fix it. I tried to find a solution to this problem, but I can't seem to fix it. Here is my code in index.ejs. A little help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   
 <%- include('layouts/header'); -%>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="post.html">Sample Post</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <%include('layouts/navbar'); ->

        <!-- Page Header-->
        <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('assets/img/home-bg.jpg')">
            <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <div class="site-heading">
                            <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
                            <span class="subheading">A Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Main Content-->
        <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
            <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                    <!-- Post preview-->
                    <div class="post-preview">
                        <a href="post.html">
                            <h2 class="post-title">Man must explore, and this is exploration at its greatest</h2>
                            <h3 class="post-subtitle">Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up</h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="post-meta">
                            Posted by
                            <a href="#!">Start Bootstrap</a>
                            on September 24, 2022
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Divider-->
                    <hr class="my-4" />
                    <!-- Post preview-->
                    <div class="post-preview">
                        <a href="post.html"><h2 class="post-title">I believe every human has a finite number of heartbeats. I don't intend to waste any of mine.</h2></a>
                        <p class="post-meta">
                            Posted by
                            <a href="#!">Start Bootstrap</a>
                            on September 18, 2022
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Divider-->
                    <hr class="my-4" />
                    <!-- Post preview-->
                    <div class="post-preview">
                        <a href="post.html">
                            <h2 class="post-title">Science has not yet mastered prophecy</h2>
                            <h3 class="post-subtitle">We predict too much for the next year and yet far too little for the next ten.</h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="post-meta">
                            Posted by
                            <a href="#!">Start Bootstrap</a>
                            on August 24, 2022
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Divider-->
                    <hr class="my-4" />
                    <!-- Post preview-->
                    <div class="post-preview">
                        <a href="post.html">
                            <h2 class="post-title">Failure is not an option</h2>
                            <h3 class="post-subtitle">Many say exploration is part of our destiny, but it’s actually our duty to future generations.</h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="post-meta">
                            Posted by
                            <a href="#!">Start Bootstrap</a>
                            on July 8, 2022
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Divider-->
                    <hr class="my-4" />
                    <!-- Pager-->
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4"><a class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" href="#!">Older Posts →</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Footer-->
        <footer class="border-top">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <ul class="list-inline text-center">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fab fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="small text-center text-muted fst-italic">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2022</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
<%- include('layouts/footer'): -%>
<%- include('layouts/scripts'); -%>
        </footer>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6IAJ.png)

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text and not as image ...

Comment: Mind to share, *what* error you get ...

Comment: I already check and the error is not the ejs..There is other error in the coding that I need to find..Btw thanks for helping

Comment: Well if the error is not in the ejs, how would anyone be able to help you if the only thing you show is the ejs ...

Comment: The problem already solve..Thank you for helping